# How to implement the os feature snap windows?

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, frame

I want to create a JFrame with a custom titlebar and thats why i removed the default one:

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

Now the titlebar is gone but there are also a few features missing. One of them is a Windows os feature that allows you to snap the frame to a certain position when you dragg the frame to the top, left or right.

[snap Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241)

Is there a way to implement this feature with an undecorated frame?